# Open cart checkout conform button in tpl file,I need to show error massage

Tags: php, opencart

In Open cart checkout process when some one click on conform button file Then order is placed in order table. 
But this not true because when click continue button (T & C) than order is placed in order table/order_product_table and after click conform button order status change 0 to 1 and order is show in admin panel 0 is default order status which store in database on continue button click.
I am working in Version 2.1.0.1 
so my question is I need to show error massage in conform file how to do this.
give some tutorial and extra link or codes.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: This forum is for getting help with code you put together but doesn't work the way you hoped for. Your question doesn't exactly qualify.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) And [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i got answer of my question if show error massage in front end of open cart then crate function of model file and return true and false and pass to controller (call function) than pass to html file in array.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show error massage in file than pass variable model->controller->view here code example.

```
 if ($condition== null) {

     $errordistance = "error massage";

}else {
  some condition;
  }return array(
       'order_id' => $order_id,
       'errordistance' => $errordistance,
       );
```

above code put in model it return two array value on controller.

```
 $array = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($order_data);
 if ($array['errordistance'] == null ) {
     $this->session->data['order_id'] = $array['order_id'];
    }

if ($array['errordistance'] == true) {

       $data['error'] = $this->language->get('error_distance');
}
else {
      $data['error'] = null;
 }
```

put above code in controller this code call a model file function before it load model file in controller.and return some value.

```
<?php if ($error) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error; ?>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

put above code in html file if error have some value(true) it show error massage otherwise not.i hope it's helpful.